# Descartes and volontarism

Tags: descartes

Was Descartes a volontarist (= Voluntarism is "any metaphysical or psychological system that assigns to the will (Latin: voluntas) a more predominant role than that attributed to the intellect" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voluntarism_(philosophy)))?

This [Encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/united-states-and-canada/us-history/voluntarism) seems to say no.

But this [Encyclopedia](https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/volontarisme/), by a quite ambiguous wording, seems to say yes:

> It [= Volontarism] inspires theologies (Duns Scotus), philosophies (Schopenhauer,
> Nietzsche, and also Descartes), psychologies (Wundt, Burloud),
> sociologies (Weber, Tönnies, to a certain extent Talcott Parsons and
> Alain Touraine)
> (Translation DeepL from French checked by myself)

Comment: Maybe... maybe not. The search for "labels" in philosophy is quite frustrating.

Comment: [Descartes' modal metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-modal/) seem to involve a claim that correct answers to questions of necessary/eternal ideas are answers decided by divine fiat. We have to venture into territory like the question of [iterated modality](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43046715) to get at how this kind of talk (from a Descartes-sympathetic POV) would be best phrased, and I'm not sure divine voluntarism remains preeminent on this deeper level, but perhaps it does.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree - I'm not sure we should try to make any particular philosopher or philosophy fall into a nice little box like this. I'm not sure what is gained by that: even if a label can be appended to a name, the label itself will probably have multiple understandings by various people.

Comment: There are many labels in philosophy that mean different things in different contexts, libertarianism is one, voluntarism is another. Yes, Descartes arguably was a [theological/modal voluntarist](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-61712-1_11) and no, it is not the voluntarism that you describe in the post. Even his "voluntarism" about beliefs is a shaky proposition, see [O'Hear](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3750196), and that is still not metaphysical or psychological voluntarism.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there philosophers or schools of philosophy who opposed to volontarism ("any metaphysical or psychological system that assigns to the will (Latin: voluntas) a more predominant role than that attributed to the intellect")?